# Image from multipart form data is parsed incorrectly in GET request

Tags: javascript, java, angular, postgresql

I'm trying to read the image send in multipart response and use it in my app. My backend service is returning two parts, first with meta-data and second with actual image's bytes.
Image is held in PostgreSQL in bytea column.

To save image I'm using [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) package.

Example of response look something like that:

```
--977f8983-13a8-4aea-b8ba-075803ad4790
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imageData"
Content-Type: application/json

{"idUser":5}
--977f8983-13a8-4aea-b8ba-075803ad4790
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

*image's bytes*
--977f8983-13a8-4aea-b8ba-075803ad4790--
```

Here's my code where I'm trying to save image

```
getImage().then(response => {
  if (response.status === 200) {
  return response.formData()
  }
})
.then(fd => {
  if (fd instanceof FormData) {
    const blob = new Blob([fd.get('image')],{
      type:'image/png'
    })
    saveAs(blob, 'image.png');
  }
});
```

As result, I get a corrupted png that is almost twice in terms of size as the original. I used the same approach in different parts of my code, and there it worked well

I've tried to save it a different way, but it resulted in a 1kb png file containing index.html of site

```
getImage().then(response => {
  if (response.status === 200) {
  return response.formData()
  }
})
.then(fd => {
  if (fd instanceof FormData) {
    saveAs(fd.get('image'), 'image.png');
  }
});
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for all suggestions.

Edit: Added backend code

Logic

```
@Inject
    ImageRepository repository;

public Response getUserImage(Long idUser) {
    var entity = repository.findByIdActiveUser(idUser);
    var image = new UsrImage();
    image.setIdUser(entity.getUsrUserEntity().getId());       
    var multipartEntity = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
    multipartEntity.addFormData("imageData", image, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    multipartEntity.addFormData("image", entity.getImage(), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    return Response.ok(multipartEntity,MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).build();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "usr_image")
public class UsrImageEntity {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
    private Long idUser;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private byte[] image;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private UsrUserEntity usrUserEntity;
    enter code here
    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public UsrUserEntity getUsrUserEntity() {
        return usrUserEntity;
    }

    public void setUsrUserEntity(UsrUserEntity usrUserEntity) {
        this.usrUserEntity = usrUserEntity;
    }
}
@RequestScoped
public class UsrImageRepository implements PanacheRepositoryBase<UsrImageEntity, Long>{

    public UsrImageEntity findByIdActiveUser(Long idUser) {
        try{
            return find("select f from UsrImageEntity f INNER JOIN UsrUserEntity u ON f.usrUserEntity.id=u.id where u.status = ?1 and u.id = ?2",
                    UserStatusEnum.ACTIVE.toString(),idUser).singleResult();
        }catch (NoResultException ex){
            Log.info(ex.getMessage());
            throw new NotFoundException("There is no image for user id="+idUser);
        }catch (NonUniqueResultException ex){
            Log.info(ex.getMessage());
            throw new InternalError(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Just wondering: why is formData being sent as a response? Why not simply send the file in a GET? Also, without the server-side code it will be too hard to find the error IMO.

Comment: @Salketer I added backend side of code. It's that way by design and unfortunately, I can't change that.